# Azure Data Factory- How to construct query with if condition in the expression builder?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

i have below query in the copy activity for copying data  from list of tables into a target.
i am using foreach activity to iterate over array parameter- tables.
Now some table name contains schema as prefix, so i need to extract the schema name from the table name and construct the query. if table name doesn't contain schema name, then query should take the default name given as a parameter in the pipeline.

```
below is the parameter and value
default_schema_parameter=myschema
tables= ["testschema_table1", "table2","prodschema_table2"]
```

there are two tables which contains schema name

```
prodschema_table2
testschema_table1
prod_cust_table1
```

now i want to construct query like this as sudo code

#Expected

```
if tables item contains '_':
   select * from item.replace with '.'
else:
   select * from default_schema_parameter.item

expected query:
1.select * from prodschema.table2
2.select * from default_schema_parameter.table2
3.select * from prod.cust_table1 -- only first part spliting
```

i tried with below approach

```
@concat('SELECT * FROM ',
    if(contains(item(), '_'),
        concat(replace(split(item(), '_')[0], ' ', ''), '.', split(item(), '_')[1]),  -- Construct schema.table if '_' is present
        concat('@{default_schema_parameter}.', item())  -- Construct default_schema_parameter.table if no '_'
    )
)
```

but above code not working.
i am getting below error on

```
concat(replace(split(item(), '_')[0],

cannot fit unknown into the function parameter
```

Is there any solution to this

Comment: In what way is it "not working"?

Comment: Hi @Nick.Mc have updated with the error iam gettting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

It is not an error, it is just a warning which occurs when we use `split()[index]` function in the string expressions.

Change your expression like below and debug the pipeline.

```
@concat('SELECT * FROM ',
    if(contains(item(), '_'),
        concat(split(item(), '_')[0], '.', split(item(), '_')[1]),
        concat(pipeline().parameters.default_schema_parameter,'.',item())
    )
)
```

It won't give any error on the pipeline debug.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

> i want to only split the first appearence of _" so it should be 'prod.cust_table1' but currently above code makes spliting in all occurance of prod.cust.table1.

Use the below dynamic expression to achieve this requirement.

```
@concat('SELECT * FROM ',
    if(contains(item(), '_'),
        concat(split(item(), '_')[0], '.', replace(item(),concat(split(item(), '_')[0],'_'),'')),
        concat(pipeline().parameters.default_schema_parameter,'.',item())
    )
)
```

This expression will give the table name by replacing the string `"schema_"` with an empty string(`''`) from current `@item()`.

[image]

Comment: hi @Rakesh, the above code working as expected for the table names
eg: test_table1
however if the table name is prod_cust_table1, in this case, i want to only split the first appearence of _" so it should be 'prod.cust_table1'
but currently above code makes spliting in all occurance of 
prod.cust.table1. I have added additional case

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check it.